# Docker Compose: Log output to both a file and stdout

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sh, exec, tee

I am trying to log the output of an application to both a file and stdout.
Only logging the output to stdout and only logging the output to a file works, however the combination of the two does not work as expected.

Here are simplified versions of docker-compose.yml and a startup script.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    web:
        image: node:14
        command: sh "/app/scripts/init-app.sh"
        init: true
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
```

**init-app.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Exit script immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
set -e

# Install and configure app
[...]

# Start app
exec ./app
```

The above configuration works, but outputs only to stdout.

**Modification #1** (last line of init script):

```
# Start app and log output to file
exec ./app >> "/app/log.txt" 2>&1
```

This configuration works also, logging the output to a file, but not to stdout.

**Modification #2** (last line of init script):

```
# Start app and log output to both a file and stdout
exec ./app 2>&1 | tee -a "/app/log.txt"
```

This correctly outputs to both a file and stdout, but it breaks the container's start/stop functionality.

Details:
Despite being called with `exec`, `./app` doesn't run as PID 1 when called with `tee`.
This is a problem, because when the container is stopped (via CLI or GUI), docker sends a stop signal to the process with PID 1. The `./app` process doesn't receive the signal and therefore `./app` doesn't stop.

How is it possible to log the output to both a file and stdout without breaking the start/stop functionality?

// Edit: Fixed modification #1

// Edit2: Added "init: true" to docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've heard a best practice :

- Logs are to be treated as a stream.
- the app itself should not manage logging (redirections, storage, etc), only writing data.

If i apply this, docker should be the only one in charge for managing this stream.

If you accept this principle you can leave you start script with only

```
exec ./app
```

you can start your app by running

```
docker-compose up web
```

control-c is available if needed.

You can access the logs in another terminal and redirect them to a file

```
docker-compose logs -f web > web.log
```

I dont see the use case, but if you want to do both starting and logging to stdout and loging to a file all the time then

```
# run and detach
docker-compose up -d web

# save logs to a file in the background
docker-compose logs -f web > web.log 2>&1 &

# reattach to the container to be able to do control-c
# it will not rerun the container, just reattach
docker-compose up web
```

Comment: Can you cite the source for this best practice?

Comment: i found it : 12 rules for scalable applications : https://12factor.net/logs

Comment: And how do you capture stdout to a file outside of the container in cases where the container doesn't stay running?

Comment: it's literally what i explain, and what my example does : web.log is outside of the container and contains stdout

Answer (score 2):

could you utilize the `logging` [capabilties](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#logging) of docker-compose to have both, printed stdout and a log file?

> Only the json-file and journald drivers make the logs available directly from docker-compose up and docker-compose logs. Using any other driver does not print any logs

Comment: An example would really help.